# Bootstrap DOM properties - getElementById or $(" ")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap and jQuery, whats the best way to set properties of a DOM element?

For a div with id="myDiv", I can modify it via two methods:

- `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "test123";`
- `$("#myDiv").html("test456");`

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2S8a/)

Is there any benefit in using one over the other?

Comment: Speed is the only difference. It like either choosing the highway or taking the residential road. You end up at the same place, but faster.

Comment: Answers to this question are probably going to be opinion-based. I tend to use the jQuery functions as they are more concise and can abstract away browser compatibility issues. In most (all?) cases, the jQuery functions are slower. It's usually not that much slower that it matters, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @JasonP More like, in *all* cases, the jQuery functions are slower...

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://vanilla-js.com/) here.

Comment: I'd get into the habit of moving away from jQuery. It's definitely not as popular as it once was, and things like GSAP crush it in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use jQuery to shorten down the length of the code you would actually write in JavaScript. Otherwise they're same, jQuery is a JavaScript's Library nothing else.

So, if you're using jQuery.

You should use

```
$('#myDiv').html('text');
```

It is the same thing that the code in JavaScript would do

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "test123";
```

Same goal, less stress and less codes.

Comment: I like how readable Vanilla JS is. For instance, you can literally read the JS here as "document get element by id "myDiv" innerHTML set to "test123"". Try doing that with the jQuery one and it's nothing like what you type.

Comment: I dislike how verbose it is. I value readability, not speakability. I prefer c# over VB for the same reason: more concise, less verbose.

Comment: C# is strongly-typed and quite verbose. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a third party library, thus u're getting a dependency (including law). 
When you use document.getElementById u get less dependency and defently need less think about licences, GPL, what-to-do-when-I-need-more-or-sell-or-kind-of and everythin else ..
 ..

for me better:

```
myfunction_changeDivContent(divName,content){
      document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are already using jQuery, I suggest, that you use `$("#myDiv").html("test456");` for your purposes, since it makes code more uniform. Not a big deal otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, *"Is there any benefit in using one over the other?"*